# similarity or difference between on and in

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, nouns

Last week my friend asked me if I found the information that he asked me to find. And I said yes. He asked how did I find about it. I said i found the information in my computer, and he said that, I should say like this,that I found the information on my computer and not in my computer. Why, is it correct to say on my computer than saying in my computer?

Comment: Do you mean "on and in" instead of "on and it"?

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us what you think, what research you have done, what you found out, and why you're still unsure.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is correct: we find information **on** the computer, we also move files and install programs *on the computer*. It is similar to how we say that we watch the news *on TV*, listen to music or a talk show *on the radio*. In all these cases we are not talking about the physical objects themselves but their concept or idea. (It doesn't really matter what actual TV set, computer, or radio receiver we use to find some info, watch a show, or listen to the news.)

You would use "**in** the computer" if you referred to the physical object:
There is 8 GB RAM and 256 GB hard drive in the computer I am thinking of buying.

Also, of course, we use "on" if we talk about something lying on top of the physical objects, the "body" of the computer:

> Ann: "Did you see my book?"
>
> Bob: "Yes, it's on the computer."

Comment: I think you mean _lying on_ not _laying on_. It is bad advice to say the OP does not need to show their research, it is one of the most common reason questions get closed.

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you. 
I am not exactly sure why it has any importance what information OP had to find for her friend and how they found it but I removed my "bad advice" all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Most things related to using computers, phones, tablets or the internet tend to use "on" in English.

- I usually listen to music **on** my phone.
- I love watching videos **on** Youtube.
- I am learning English using the app **on** my tablet.
- I found the information **on** my computer.